# How to make two click listener for recycle view list item such as , on item click and favorite item click?

Tags: android

how can we make on item click and favorite item  click in recycle view list item ?

Comment: can you be more specific please ? as it stands, this question is too broad and cannot be answered

Comment: I have  a product  list item  and i want to click specific  item to view product details  and meanwhile  favorite  icon such as  like option in item

Answer (score 0):

Add two method in your interface

```
public interface  OnRecyclerViewItemClick{
void  listItemClick(int  position,int  Id); 
void  favoriteItemclick(int  position,int  Id)
}
```

Or just add two interface.